# Why does aspnet_compiler succeed with updateable flag, but fail otherwise?

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

We're investigating the feasibility of pre-compiling our website to improve site startup time.  What we're trying to avoid is any invocation of `csc.exe` when users hit the site.  While csc.exe is running, IIS won't service any additional HTTP requests.  This limits the frequency and speed with which we can release new binaries to our site, since it takes hours to deploy the code and warm-up each of the web servers in our farm.

I've got `aspnet_compiler.exe` compiling the site in updateable mode (i.e. with the `-u` flag), but after testing, it looks like IIS is still calling out to `csc.exe` to compile controls/pages.

```
> aspnet_compiler -v / -p F:\Projects\Website\webroot -u F:\BuildOutput\Website
```

So, I tried without the `-u` flag, and now I'm getting compilation errors:

```
> aspnet_compiler -v / -p F:\Projects\Website\webroot F:\BuildOutput\Website
/Tool/Controls/ToolCustomDateRangePicker.ascx(8): error ASPPARSE: Unknown server 
tag 'SharedControls:DateRangePicker'.
```

When I open `/Tool/Controls/ToolCustomDateRantPicker.ascx`, it references `SharedControls:DateRangePicker` correctly:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharedControls" TagName="DateRangePicker" 
             Src="../../common/Controls/DateRangePicker.ascx" %>
```

What gives?  **Why does `aspnet_compiler` compile my site correctly when its updateable but fails when compiling it so its non-updateable?**

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue - it seems as if using -u option doesn't actually compile the inner code - so it will need to be compiled at runtime.
From:MSDN

> When you use this option, code blocks in .aspx files (that is, code
>   located in script elements or between <% and %> tags) are not
>   compiled. Therefore, if there are compile errors in those code blocks,
>   you will see the error only at run time, because the .aspx file is
>   fully compiled only then. It is generally unsafe to use this option
>   for a site that relies on code blocks in .aspx files.